# Como executar Procedures com o Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

Como posso executar uma store procedure com o Dapper?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Supondo que você queria obter o resultado numa variável do tipo `Cliente`.

```
var cliente = connection.Query<Cliente>("spClientes", new {Id = 1}, 
                                    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).First();
```

O primeiro parâmetro é o nome da procedure, o segundo são os parâmetros passados para ela e o terceiro é o tipo de comando que será executado.

Comment: Funcionou muito obrigado!